# Create method with unlimited expression parameters?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have created a repository method with the following signature:

```
T Get<TProperty>(int id, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> include)
```

This works fine but I would like to extend it to take in an unlimited number of includes. I cannot simply use params because each include will return a different TProperty.

Is there a nice way around this or do I have to create several overloads for 1, 2 or 3 includes for example?

Comment: Are the different TProperty types related?  Or completely separate types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the TProperty types can be different, and if you want to make them different types, then you'd need several overloads.

```
T Get<TProperty>(int id, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> include) { ... }
T Get<TProperty1, TProperty2>(int id, Expression<Func<T, TProperty1>> include1, Expression<Func<T, TProperty2>> include2)
```

**OR** you could use:

```
T Get(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
```

And rely on the covariance of the Func generic delegate, but then you'd have to handle the fact you're losing a bit of type safety.

Because Func is covariance on the return type, this means that if your delegate expects a return of object, you can still pass it a delegate with a narrower return type (though warning, with covariance value types aren't covariantly compatible with object, only reference types).

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted won't allow you to return a different TProperty but only the type you will specify at runtime as `<TProperty>`

You could use Params and use Object instead of the generic type